# recorrer Resulset y mostrarlo en JTextFiled

Tags: java, mysql

Necesito crear un método que recorra una a una las filas mi bdd, con ResulSet logro mostrar la primer fila en mis campos de texto pero lo que necesito es que al clickar "siguiente" me muestre la fila que sigue, entiendo que debo utilizar el método next() del ResulSet pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo.

VentanaPrincipal.java:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class VentanaPrincipal extends JFrame{
public VentanaPrincipal() {

GestionBDD gsBdd = new GestionBDD();

  JButton btnConsultar = new JButton("CONSULTAR");
    btnConsultar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                gsBdd.consultarBBDD();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            dispose();
        }
    });
```

GestionBDD.java:

```
 public void consultarBBDD() throws SQLException {
    VentanaConsulta vc = new VentanaConsulta();

    try {

            miStatement = con.createStatement();
            miResul = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pelicula");
        
            while (miResul.next()) {
                
                String tiempo=String.valueOf(miResul.getInt("duracion"));
                    vc.txtTitulo.setText(miResul.getString("titulo"));
                    vc.txtDirector.setText(miResul.getString("director"));
                    vc.txtPais.setText(miResul.getString("pais"));
                    vc.txtDuracion.setText(tiempo);
                    vc.txtGenero.setText(miResul.getString("genero"));          
    
            }   
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

VentanaConsulta.java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
public class VentanaConsulta extends JFrame {

```
protected JTextField txtDirector;
protected JTextField txtPais;
protected JTextField txtDuracion;
protected JTextField txtGenero;
protected JTextField txtTitulo;

  public VentanaConsulta() {
  
 JButton btnSiguiente = new JButton("SIGUIENTE");
    btnSiguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
           //METODO QUE ME MUESTRE LA SIGUIENTE FILA
        }
    });
```

Comment: Creaste una nueva ventana y en ella cargaste los datos del resultset?. De ser así lo ideal sería que cargues los JTextField en el constructor de esa ventana, de esa forma puedes trabajar con en resulset tambien desde esa ventana

Comment: Perdón, debería ser mas especifico, lo que hice es crear un crud, para eso tengo una ventana con 4 botones(consultar,insertar,eliminar,actualizar), el botón "consular" abre la VentanaConsulta donde tengo que mostrar los campos de la tabla, se entiende? hay alguna manera mas sencilla de hacerlo, me esta saliendo humo por las orejas...

Comment: Y el botón siguiente dónde se encuentra?, podrias agregar capturas para entender mejor

Comment: subí unas imágenes para hacerlos mas descriptivo

Answer (score 0):

La clase VentanaPrincipal puedes dejarla como está

Vamos a modificar un poco GestionBDD.java para que reciba VentanaConsulta como parámetro y creamos un nuevo método llamado mostrarSiguiente donde transferimos el código que ya tenías en el if:

```
public  void consultarBBDD(VentanaConsulta vc) throws SQLException {
    try {
        miStatement = con.createStatement();
        miResul = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pelicula");
        mostrarSiguiente(vc);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Este es el método mostrarSiguiente:

```
public void mostrarSiguiente(VentanaConsulta ventana){
    try {
        if (miResul.next()) {                   
            ventana.txtTitulo.setText(miResul.getString("titulo"));
            ventana.txtDirector.setText(miResul.getString("director"));
            ventana.txtDuracion.setText(miResul.getString("duracion"));
            ventana.txtPais.setText(miResul.getString("pais"));
            ventana.txtGenero.setText(miResul.getString("genero"));          
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

VentanaConsulta.java también la modificamos un poco para que se envíe a si misma y podamos agregar los datos de texto:

```
public class VentanaConsulta extends JFrame {
    protected JTextField txtDirector;
    protected JTextField txtPais;
    protected JTextField txtGenero;
    protected JTextField txtTitulo;

    public VentanaConsulta() {
        GestionBDD gestionBDD = new GestionBDD(); 
        gestionBDD.consultarBBDD(this);

        JButton btnSiguiente = new JButton("SIGUIENTE");
        btnSiguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                gestionBDD.mostrarSiguiente(this);
```

Espero que lo pruebes y me avises si te sirvió

Comment: Gracias por el intento pero no funciona, me da un Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JTextField.setText(String)" because "vc.txtTitulo" is null

Comment: Ok... sin problemas... yo también estoy aprendiendo contigo jaja... si no te molesta puedes actualizar el código que tienes ahora para volver a revisar y ver si podemos encontrar la solución

Comment: Sigo probando pero no  lo logro, ya lo actualicé, he cambiado algunas cosas, ya que me parece que esta mas claro si desde VentanaPrincipal.java me cargue VentanaConsulta con los datos directamente, así dejo el boton "siguiente"(VentanaCosulta)  limpio para implementar el metodo que me muestre la siguiente fila...

Comment: En GestionBDD.java puedes usar el while para cargar los datos en un arraylist y despues mostrar los datos con el botón siguiente

Answer (score 0):

Ya logré solucionarlo, lo que hice fué:
1)crear el metodo listaDB que me devuelve un Arraylist con todos los campos de mi tabla (gracias Rocker) utilizando un delimitador para diferenciar cada campo.
2)crear un método que separe el arraylist utilizando el delimitador.

3)En la clase donde muestro los campos utilizar los 2 métodos para llenar los JTextField

Obtengo valores de la BDD:

```
    public ArrayList<String> listaBD() throws SQLException {
    
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    Statement stmt =  null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    
    String query="SELECT * FROM pelicula";
    
    
    try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);
    
    
    while (rs.next()) {
        
        lista.add(rs.getString("titulo")+"-"+rs.getString("director")+"-"+
                    rs.getString("pais")+"-"+rs.getString("duracion")+"-"+
                rs.getString("genero"));
            
        }
                System.out.println(lista);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
    }
    return lista;
    
}
```

Separar cadena:

```
   public String[] separarDato (String dato, String delimiter) {        
    
    String[] temp;
    temp=dato.split(delimiter);
    return temp;
}
```

VentanaConsulta.java:

```
    JButton btnSiguiente = new JButton("SIGUIENTE");
    btnSiguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {           
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
            peliActual++;
            
            if (pelicula.size()==0) { 
                System.out.println("NO HAY PELICULAS");
            
            }else {
                String dato[] = Main.gbb.separarDato(pelicula.get(peliActual-1),"-");

                txtTitulo.setText(dato[0]);                 
                txtDirector.setText(dato[1]);
                txtPais.setText(dato[2]);
                txtDuracion.setText(dato[3]);
                txtGenero.setText(dato[4]);
                if (pelicula.size()==peliActual) {
                    btnSiguiente.setEnabled(false);             
                
                }
            }
            
            }           
    });
```